# Find files, gtar them and create a report

Tags: java, linux, unix, jenkins

I am creating a job for Jenkins, that uses Java.

I want to gzip all the files named 'log' in path $CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs .

I would do that with this command:

> find $CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs -name 'log' -exec gtar

I have many logs in this path and I somehow have to create a loop (for each?)
that would gtar 'log' files in the mentioned path and I also want to get a report which logs(full path) were gtared and for how much storage I saved by by gtaring each log.

Comment: A typo, I meant gzip instead of gtar.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need find.

Just run:

```
du -h -d 0 "$CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs"
```

This will get the space before running gzip

then:

```
gzip "$CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs/"*logs
```

to zip the files

and finally:

```
du -h -d 0 "$CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs"
```

To get the space again.

Comment: I get this:
user@host:~$ du -h --max-depth=0 "$CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs"
du: illegal option -- max-depth=0
usage: du [-dorx] [-a|-s] [-h|-k|-m] [-H|-L] [file...]

Comment: Try using -d instead. I have changed accordingly.

Comment: Wow this does the trick ! The trickiest part for me now is to use du -h -d 0 "$CIDR_CFG_DIR/jobs" to  SORT files by SIZE.